# Include a column in the query which is not a part of the query

Tags: sql

I have created a Materialized View and have a query which works fine.
Now I have to add a column in the SQL so that when the Materialized View is used in a `QUERY(QUERY MANAGER)` a few columns will be `UNPIVOTED` and put in the "New column"

I am unsure how to add the column which is not part of any where condition.

This is how my query starts after `E.Accessible` I should have one more column name.

```
 SELECT distinct D.OPRID, O.oprdefndesc,
    RU.ROLENAME ROLE, D.OPRCLASS PERMISSION_LIST,  
    E.TREE_NAME,  E.ACCESS_GROUP,  E.ACCESSIBLE,`
```

Finally  my query has:
`OPRID,OPRDEFNDESC,ROLE,PERMISSION_LIST,TREE_NAME,ACCESS_GROUP,ACCESSIBLE,"NEW COLUMN TOBE INCLUDED",NODE1,NODE2,NODE3,NODE4,NODE5,NODE6,NODE7,NODE8`

When the query is built all the nodes will be unpivoted and put in the new column.

Comment: Can you provide details on sample data and desired results?

Comment: You mean the  sql, ?> shd i post there? above i have given the column for the final result.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the column is in one of the tables already included in the query, just add the column.

If it's on another table you have to add a JOIN to the table and then you can add the column.

Columns in the SELECT portion do NOT have to be in the WHERE clause; just in the tables selected from.